# Python - Removing parentheses and quotation marks

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I've been trying to remove pair parentheses(including text between them), unbalanced parentheses and quotation marks from the string.

What I've done so far:

```
import re

sample_text = '""sads"add"sfsfdsfds()()(0sefdAAAsfs)dasdad(asd'
res = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', sample_text))
```

It matches with only `()()(0sefdAAAsfs)` part of the text. Unbalanced and quotation marks left unmatched. What can be done to improve above regex?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really something that a regular expression is suited for, so is not the right tool for the job. Having said that, you can use the following pattern to see if there is an opening paren, then zero or more non-paren, and a matching closing paren:

```
\([^)+]*\)
```

Substitute a `"` or `'` or `[` or whatever for the other types of matching components.

But again, this would not work with something like this:

```
(asdf))))))))
```

[image]

Long story short: it's not a problem that a regular expression is capable of solving. Try testing it out here: https://regex101.com/r/bdiK5W/2.